# Filtering a function' output for a new continued function

Tags: php, functions, filters, tags, array

Alright let me explain. I am using a function to get all Wordpress Tags and display them. That is fine.:

What I'm trying to do is display these tags first in one place where space is limited and then continuing to display them else where without conflicts.

```
$tagargs = array(
        'number' => 60,
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'order' => 'DESC'
        );

$sunnytags =  get_tags( $tagargs );
foreach ($sunnytags as $tag) { 
$string .= '<a class="tag2" href="'. get_tag_link($tag->term_id) .'">'. $tag->name . '</a>';
} 
return $string;
```

That's the code. The place its in can only display 15 tags and then I'd have to continue the display somewhere else, which means running the same code but filtering it against the first one.

I have explored the php vocabulary but Havent got it working yet...

I thought about using an array filter for the new function that would filter out the first 15 tags and go on from there.

array array_filter ( array $array [, callable $callback [, int $flag = 0 ]] )

What are your thoughts? can anyone help me=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a standard `for` loop instead:

```
$sunnytags = get_tags ($tagargs);
$count = count ($sunnytags);
for ($i = 0; $i < ($count < 15 ? $count : 15); $i++) {
    $string .= '<a class="tag2" href="'. get_tag_link ($sunnytags[$i]->term_id) .'">'. $sunnytags[$i]->name . '</a>';
}
```

And then later, whether you re-run the query or (better still) save `$sunnytags` for later use, you can get the rest of the elements like this:

```
for ($i = 15; $i < $count; $i++) {
    // Process the rest of them here as $sunnytags[$i]
}
```

Comment: Coding maestro! Works as intended. Infinitely grateful for the quick and thorough response. The internet salutes you!